# How can i display query string in a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, query-string, querystringparameter

I have the following code to display query string in my view I used `ViewContext.RouteData.Values` but it only display `id` how can i display the rest query, my url looks like this `http://localhost:XXXX/Products/Product/Edit/4437?ProductName=ASSY 670975 6X5`

I have used the following code to get data from url

```
var ProductID = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
var ProductName= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["ProductName"];
```

I'm able to display 4437 or the `ProductID` value, How can i display `ProductName` or  `ASSY 670975 6X5` in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var ProductName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"]
```

Comment: Thank you! but i get `The name Request doesnt exist in the curent context, I also tried `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ProductName"]` same message on `HttpContext doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you~ this worked for me @Context.Request.Query["ProductName"]